# iptables rules to permit GitHub Actions from breaking (chains default to DROP)

Tags: continuous-integration, networking, github

Assuming my iptables rules default to DROP on the INPUT and OUTPUT chains, what is the bare minimum set of rules that I must add to my chains to prevent a script running in GitHub Actions from stalling indefinitely?

I'm using (free) GitHub Actions for my open-source application's CI/CD infrastructure. When I push changes to github.com, it automatically spins up an Ubuntu 18.04 linux server in Microsoft's cloud that checks-out my repo and executes a BASH script to build my application.

For security reasons, early on in my build script I install and setup some very restrictive `iptables` rules that default to `DROP` on the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains. I poke a hole in the firewall for `127.0.0.1`, `RELATED/ESTABLISHED` on `INPUT`, and only permit the `_apt` user to send traffic through `OUTPUT`.

This works great when I run the build script in a docker container on my local system. But--as I just learned--when it runs with GitHub Actions, it stalls indefinitely. Clearly, the instance itself needs to be able to communicate out to GitHub's servers in order to finish. And I appear to have broken that.

So the question is: what `-j ACCEPT` rules should I add to my `iptables` `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains to only permit the bare necessities for GitHub Actions executions to proceed as usual?

For reference, here's the snippet from my build script that sets-up my firewall:

```
##################
# SETUP IPTABLES #
##################

# We setup iptables so that only the apt user (and therefore the apt command)
# can access the internet. We don't want insecure tools like `pip` to download
# unsafe code from the internet.

${SUDO} iptables-save > /tmp/iptables-save.`date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j DROP
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 100 -j ACCEPT # apt uid = 100
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

${SUDO} ip6tables-save > /tmp/ip6tables-save.`date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -s ::1/128 -j DROP
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -j DROP
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -s ::1/128 -d ::1/128 -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 100 -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

# attempt to access the internet as root. If it works, exit 1
curl -s 1.1.1.1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "ERROR: iptables isn't blocking internet access to unsafe tools. You may need to run this as root (and you should do it inside a VM)"
        exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by running your build script in a docker container and applying your iptables rules inside that container, which won't affect the host `runner`'s connectivity.

For example, if the below script is executed in a GitHub Actions job (in the Ubuntu 18.04 GitHub shared runner), it will run the build script (`docker_script.sh`) in a debian docker container that has no internet connectivity, except from the `_apt` user.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

###################
# INSTALL DEPENDS #
###################

apt-get -y install docker.io

##################
# DOWNLOAD IMAGE #
##################

# At the time of writing, Docker Content Trust is 100% security theater without
# explicitly adding the root public keys to the $HOME/.docker/trust/ directory
#
#  * https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/6#issuecomment-700050760
#  * https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238529/how-to-list-all-of-the-known-root-keys-in-docker-docker-content-trust
#  * https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2752

docker -D pull debian:stable-slim

#################
# CREATE SCRIPT #
#################

tmpDir=`mktemp -d`
pushd "${tmpDir}"

cat << EOF > docker_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# SETTINGS #
SUDO=/usr/bin/sudo

# DEPENDS #
${SUDO} apt-get update
${SUDO} apt-get install iptables curl

# IPTABLES #

# We setup iptables so that only the apt user (and therefore the apt command)
# can access the internet. We don't want insecure tools like `pip` to download
# unsafe code from the internet.

${SUDO} iptables-save > /tmp/iptables-save.`date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j DROP
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 100 -j ACCEPT # apt uid = 100
${SUDO} iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

${SUDO} ip6tables-save > /tmp/ip6tables-save.`date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -s ::1/128 -j DROP
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A INPUT -j DROP
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -s ::1/128 -d ::1/128 -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 100 -j ACCEPT
${SUDO} ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

# attempt to access the internet as root. If it works, exit 1
curl 1.1.1.1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "ERROR: iptables isn't blocking internet access to unsafe tools. You may need to run this as root (and you should do it inside a VM)"
        exit 1
fi

# BUILD #

# ...
# <DO BUILD HERE>
# ...

exit 0
EOF
chmod +x docker_script.sh

##############
# DOCKER RUN #
##############

docker run --rm --cap-add "NET_ADMIN" -v "${tmpDir}:/root/shared_volume" debian:stable-slim /bin/bash -c "cd /root/shared_volume && docker_script.sh"

# exit cleanly
exit 0
```

Note that:

1. You have to execute the `docker run` command manually rather than just specify the `container:` in the GitHub Actions yaml file in order to add the `NET_ADMIN` capability. See Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959783/how-to-run-script-in-docker-container-with-additional-capabilities-docker-exec/64045054#64045054
2. This is a security risk unless you pin the root signing keys before calling `docker pull`. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238529/how-to-list-all-of-the-known-root-keys-in-docker-docker-content-trust
3. The above script should be executed as root. For example, prepend `sudo` to it in the `run:` key for the step in the GitHub Actions workflow.